# Is it possible to get the sum of a dictionary JSON with values of different data types in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, sum

I am trying to get the sum of the values from a dictionary within a JSON file, but some of the values are a different data type. Only the values that are numbers I want added.

```
{"id": "id-1", "id name": "city 1", "Level": "software engineer", "days total 1": "100", "days total 2": "111", "days total 3": "56", "days total 4": "158", "days total 5": "48", "days total 6": "37", "days total 7": "188", "days total 8": "121", "date": "04/06/2022 00:00:00 AM"}
```

Is it possible to still get the sum of the values from this dictionary JSON?

**sum(int(dictionary.values()))** won't work since some the strings are actually words or dates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The JSON file has both numeric and non-numeric objects in it. Do you want to add only the numeric ones or all of them?

Comment: You will have much easier time solving the problem if you define what you _want_ to happen when trying to add "100" to "software engineer"

Comment: I just want to add the numeric values from the JSON. All integers and exclude the other non-numeric values.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the sum of values that are digits

```
sum(int(x) for x in dictionary.values() if x.isdigit())
```